# Going from "wäre" and "sei" in indirect reporting to the actual (direct) discourse

Tags: subjunctive, indirect-speech, french

The question is on these two German renditions of a passage from Camus’s *L’Étranger* ([English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stranger_(novel)): *The Stranger* or *The Outsider*, [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Fremde): *Der Fremde*).

To set the context, Meursault, the first person narrator of the novel, is at trial for murder and has been in jail for several years now.  Celeste (‘er’), who ran a restaurant where Meursault used to go, is called to the witness stand.

By Uli Aumüller:

> Er wurde gefragt, ob ich Gast bei ihm **wäre**, und er hat gesagt: «Ja, aber er **war** auch ein Freund»

By Georg Goyert and Hans Georg Brenner:

> Man fragte ihn, ob ich sein Kunde **sei**, und er antwortete: «Ja, aber er **ist** auch mein Freund.»

The *ob*-clause is indirect reporting, so the reader’s mind implicitly hears (tries to hear) the actual (direct) thing spoken.

I believe then the following question arises for both *wäre* and *sei* in exactly the same way.

### Question

Is there any chance that a native German speaker will hear in the *ob*-clause a question about the past?

The meaning of my question may become more clear if we consider these potential answers.

1. A German speaker will hear a question about the **present**.  That is, he will think that the actual (direct) thing spoken at trial was the following.

   > **Ist** er Gast bei Ihnen?
   >   **Ist** er Ihr Kunde?
2. He will hear a question about the **past**.  That is, he will think the following were spoken at trial.

   > **War** er Gast bei Ihnen?
   >   **War** er Ihr Kunde?

### Background

You don’t have to read this background to answer the question.

I doubt the larger context would change the answer, but you will find it below from the two translations and Camus’s original.

I am not asking whether either version is a good translation of the French original (although I don't mind anyone commenting on that).

Some of you might wonder what was bothering me or where I was going with this question.  If anybody wants to know I don’t mind adding it to this background.  But I believe the question stands on its own as asked.

By Uli Aumüller:

> Nach einer fünfminütigen Unterbrechung, in der mein Anwalt mir sagte, alles liefe bestens, wurde Celeste vernommen, der von der Verteidigung vorgeladen war. Die Verteidigung, das war ich. Céleste warf ab und zu Blicke zu mir hinüber und drehte einen Panamahut in den Händen. Er trug den neuen Anzug, den er anhatte, wenn er manchmal sonntags mit mir zum Pferderennen ging. Aber ich glaube, er hatte seinen Kragen nicht anlegen können, denn sein Hemd wurde nur von einem Kupferknopf zusammengehalten. **Er wurde gefragt, ob ich Gast bei ihm wäre, und er hat gesagt: «Ja, aber er war auch ein Freund»**; was er von mir hielte, und er hat geantwortet, ich wäre ein Mann; was er damit meinte, und er hat erklärt, jeder wüßte doch, was das hieße; ob er bemerkt hätte, daß ich verschlossen war, und er hat nur eingeräumt, daß ich nicht redete, um nichts zu sagen.

By Georg Goyert and Hans Georg Brenner:

> Nach fünf Minuten Pause, während der mein Anwalt mir sagte, alles stehe zum Besten, wurde Celeste als Zeuge der Verteidigung vernommen. Als mein Zeuge. Ab und zu warf Celeste einen Blick auf mich und drehte seinen Panama in der Händen. Er hatte den neuen Anzug an, in dem er sonntags mit mir zum Rennen ging. Aber er war wohl mit dem Kragen nicht fertig geworden, weil nur ein Kupferknopf das Hemd vorne zusammenhielt. **Man fragte ihn, ob ich sein Kunde sei, und er antwortete: «Ja, aber er ist auch mein Freund.»** Was er über mich denke? Er antwortete, ich sei ein ganzer Kerl. Was er damit meine? Er sagte, das wisse doch jeder. Ob er nicht bemerkt habe, daß ich sehr verschlossen sei? Er gab zu, daß ich nicht spräche, wenn ich nichts zu sagen hätte.

Camus’s original in French:

> Après cinq minutes de suspension pendant lesquelles mon avocat m’a dit que tout allait pour le mieux, on a entendu Céleste qui était cité par la défense. La défense, c’était moi. Céleste jetait de temps en temps des regards de mon côté et roulait un panama entre ses mains. Il portait le costume neuf qu’il mettait pour venir avec moi, certains dimanches, aux courses de chevaux. Mais je crois qu’il n’avait pas pu mettre son col parce qu’il portait seulement un bouton de cuivre pour tenir sa chemise fermée. **On lui a demandé si j’étais son client et il a dit : « Oui, mais c’était aussi un ami »** ; ce qu’il pensait de moi et il a répondu que j’étais un homme ; ce qu’il entendait par là et il a déclaré que tout le monde savait ce que cela voulait dire ; s’il avait remarqué que j’étais renfermé et il a reconnu seulement que je ne parlais pas pour ne rien dire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that both uses are wrong here. It should be:

> Er wurde gefragt, ob ich Gast bei ihm gewesen sei, und er hat gesagt/sagte...

Or:

> Er wurde gefragt, ob ich Gast bei ihm gewesen wäre, und er hat gesagt/sagte...

The event - being a guest - took place in the past. But Konjunktiv I/II do not have a temporal meaning anymore. Therefore, Perfekt is necessary.

Comment: _Gast, Kunde_ and _Freund_ in particular can be considered long-term states not one-time roles, so the past tense or perfect aspect probably isn’t that important.

Comment: Yes, but he is and has been in prison, so he is no guest anywhere anymore.

Comment: @Veredomon You saw through my post and answered the *real* question I had.  Yes, I thought *gewesen sei* and *gewesen wäre* would make more sense. I guess what is implicit in your answer is potential answer 1 (of the original post); namely, that a German speaker would hear a question about the present in the two translations.

Comment: My French isn’t good enough, but _c’etait_ in direct speech is clearly past tense, so it should either be Aumüller’s “aber er **war** auch ein Freund” or “aber er **ist** auch ein Freund **gewesen**”. The preceding indirect speech should probably match the tense (or at least form) – as it does in both translations and the original _c’etais_ – to highlight that it is or may be different now. If the question was about the narrator’s alibi, _gewesen sei/wäre_  makes some sense, but in actual German I would expect an indicator like _damals_ or _zum fraglichen Zeitpunkt_ with indicative _war_.

Comment: @Crissov You mean in actual German you would expect: "Er wurde gefragt, ob ich damals Gast bei ihm war"? That would have suggested to me that the fictional characters were talking in the past tense. To sum up, both *war* and *gewesen sei/wäre* would have suggested to me characters talking in the past tense. (The original translations suggested characters talking in the present tense.)

Comment: @Catomic Yes, both translations (_wäre_ and _sei_) and likewise _bin_ suggest that he’s either still a guest or a regular guest, whereas _war_ and _gewesen sei/wäre/bin/war_ would indicate that the question was about the time of the crime, even without an additional marker like _damals_.